# Iterating over a function's parameters in Python (using a 2d numpy array and a list of decimals)

Tags: python, loops, numpy, matrix, iteration

I have defined a function that takes 2 parameters: a symetric matrix `M` and a probability value `p`. I want to define a function that loops over my parameters. The loop starts with a probability 0.01 and stops when it reaches `p`. On each step the function picks random lines and columns from the matrix `M` according to the probability and removes them. Then does the same thing to the new `M` with the incremented probability. I am unable to obtain results with my code

## range function that supports decimals

```
def frange(start, end, step):
    tmp = start
    while tmp < end:
        yield tmp
        tmp += step
```

## loop function (pick random rows and columns from the matrix and remove them)

```
def loop(M, p):
    for i in frange(0.01, p, 0.01):
        indices = random.sample(range(np.shape(M)[0]),
                                int(round(np.shape(M)[0] * i)))
        M = np.delete(M, indices, axis=0)  # removes rows
        M = np.delete(M, indices, axis=1)  # removes columns
        return M, indices
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, you are returning only `M` and `p` for your first index, `i=0.01`, this is because the loop will stop as soon as you return something. In addition, as you can use `range` given in python, your first function is superfluous. I suggest you to return your matrices and indices using a List for example (you can also do this with np.arrays).

```
def loop(M, p):
  mat_list  = []
  indices_list = []
  for i in range(0.01, p, 0.01):
      indices = random.sample(range(np.shape(M)[0]),
                              int(round(np.shape(M)[0] * i)))
      M = np.delete(M, indices, axis=0)  # removes rows
      M = np.delete(M, indices, axis=1)  # removes columns
      mat_list.append(M)
      indices_list.append(indices)
  return mat_list, indices_list
```

If you also want to include the probability `p`, then you have to loop through 
`range(0.01, p+0.01, 0.01)`.